# Overloading by both argument and return type in agda

Tags: overloading, agda, dependent-type

I am trying to write a function of the form `f : (X + Y) -> (Z + T)` where `X, Y, Z, T` are types and `+` is a pseudo-notation for sum type. The return type of `f` will be determined by the context i.e. say, in pseudo-agda

```
postulate x : X

t : T
t = f x -- OK, since (f : X -> T) definition is used
```

It is easy to make something like this (again in pseudo-agda, I'm trying to be concise and clear):

```
fromX : X -> X + Y
toT : Z x T -> T

t2 : T
t2 = toT (f (fromX x))
```

But this is way too noisy for what I'm trying to accomplish. I tried abusing instance finding. Here is the minimal code I wanted to work but does not type check:

```
module Agda2 where
  infix 21 _·_
  infix 19 _≡_

  data _≡_ {n} {S : Set n} (x : S) : S → Set n where
    refl : x ≡ x

  sym : ∀ {n} {S : Set n} {x y : S} → x ≡ y → y ≡ x
  sym refl = refl

  euc : ∀ {n} {S : Set n} {x y z : S} → (x ≡ y) → (x ≡ z) → (y ≡ z)
  euc refl refl = refl

  postulate A : Set

  postulate _·_ : A → A → A

  postulate associative : ∀ {a b c} → (a · b) · c ≡ a · (b · c)

  data _∈_+_ (A : Set) : Set → Set → Set where
    instance
      sum-type₁ : ∀ {B : Set} → A ∈ A + B
      sum-type₂ : ∀ {B : Set} → A ∈ B + A

  assoc : ∀ {E1 E2 : Set} {a b c d : A}
    {{_ : E1 ∈ ((a · b) · c ≡ d) + (a · (b · c) ≡ d)}}
    {{_ : E2 ∈ ((a · b) · c ≡ d) + (a · (b · c) ≡ d)}}
    → E1 → E2
  assoc {{sum-type₁}} {{sum-type₂}} eq = euc associative eq
  assoc {{sum-type₂}} {{sum-type₁}} eq = euc (sym associative) eq  
  assoc {{sum-type₂}} {{sum-type₂}} eq = eq
  assoc {{sum-type₁}} {{sum-type₁}} eq = eq

  tt : ∀ {a b c d} → (a · b) · c ≡ d → (a · (b · c) ≡ d)
  tt eq = assoc eq
```

The problem with this code is that Agda cannot infer `a, b, c, d` (I guess, but I'm not sure). I circumvent this problem by doing this:

```
  -- Everything is the same upto this point

  data _,_,_,_ (a b c d : A) : Set where
    v4 : a , b , c , d

  assoc : ∀ {E1 E2 : Set} {a b c d : A}
    {{_ : E1 ∈ ((a · b) · c ≡ d) + (a · (b · c) ≡ d)}}
    {{_ : E2 ∈ ((a · b) · c ≡ d) + (a · (b · c) ≡ d)}}
    → (a , b , c , d) → E1 → E2
  assoc {{sum-type₁}} {{sum-type₂}} _ eq = euc associative eq
  assoc {{sum-type₂}} {{sum-type₁}} _ eq = euc (sym associative) eq  
  assoc {{sum-type₂}} {{sum-type₂}} _ eq = eq
  assoc {{sum-type₁}} {{sum-type₁}} _ eq = eq

  tt : ∀ {a b c d} → (a , b , c , d) → (a · b) · c ≡ d → (a · (b · c) ≡ d)
  tt p eq = assoc p eq
```

This works, since now agda explicitly takes `a, b, c, d` as argument (again, this is what I understand, but I don't know much about agda internals). But unfortunately this is not practical since now every theorem would take an additional argument just so that type checker can infer the right type.

Why do I want to do this? What am I trying to accomplish? I'm trying to write a generic `assoc` function so that I don't have to have dozens of `assoc` functions like `assocl, assoc2, assoc' ...` in order to do associative equality reasoning. I want one function that can prove both `a(bc)=ab(c)` and `ab(c)=a(bc)` etc...

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!